# Install Realm in a Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to add Realm to my app written in swift. I have followed the tutorial and I can't seem to get it to work.  The biggest problem is that when I try to import Realm I get `No such module 'Realm'`  I don't know what else to try.  You can see my efforts below.

You can see the instructions here: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.85.0/#swft

I have also copied the instructions below:

Due to the current lack of proper infrastructure for Swift dependency management, using Realm in your project requires the following steps:

1. Add Realm as a submodule by opening the Terminal, cd-ing into your top-level project directory, and entering the command git submodule add git@github.com:realm/realm-cocoa.git
2. Open the realm-cocoa folder, and drag Realm.xcodeproj into the file navigator of your Xcode project.
3. In Xcode, navigate to the target configuration window by clicking on the blue project icon, and selecting the application target under the “Targets” section in the sidebar.
4. In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the “Build Phases” panel.
5. Expand the “Target Dependencies” gorup, and add Realm’s iOS framework.
6. Expand the “Link Binary with Libraries” group, and add Realm’s iOS framework as well as libc++.dylib.
7. Click on the + button at the top left of the panel and select “New Copy Files Phase”. Rename this new phase to “Copy Frameworks”, set the “Destination” to “Frameworks”, and add Realm.framework.
8. Drag the file at realm-cocoa/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift into the file navigator of your Xcode project, unchecking the “Copy items if needed” checkbox.

Below is what it looks like in my project:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We're working on simplifying our installation instructions. We'll post an answer to this question in a few hours, once the new instructions are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been talking with the guys at Realm, and it turns out that the latest instructions don't work with Realm <= 0.85 They changed they way the build the framework and it won't work anymore.  They said they will release 0.86 later today that should fix the problems anyone is having with Swift.  In the meantime I have a test project that anyone can take the latest framework from. https://github.com/smitt04/testRealm

**Version 0.86 is now out and this is no longer an issue.**

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure exactly why this isn't working, but here is a workaround:

1. Follow the latest instructions.
2. Create a bridging header, for example by

   - Add a new Objective-C class to your xcode project.
   - Agree to have a bridging header created
   - Delete the Objective-C class
3. Add this in the bridging header:

   `#import "Realm/Realm.h"`
4. Remove any `Import Realm` statements from your code, including from RLMSupport.swift
5. Now it should work. For example, I test with putting this in my ViewController.swift

   ```
   import UIKit

   class Person: RLMObject {
       dynamic var name = ""
       dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
   }

   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let author = Person()
           author.name = "David Foster Wallace"

           // Get the default Realm
           let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

           // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
           realm.beginWriteTransaction()
           realm.addObject(author)
           realm.commitWriteTransaction()

           // Print all Persons
           println(Person.allObjects())
       }
   }
   ```

Which prints:

```
RLMArray <0x7a243760> (
    [0] Person {
        name = David Foster Wallace;
        birthdate = 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000;
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Swift installation instructions were long and convoluted, so I'm not surprised you and several other users ran into issues.

Please follow the latest installation instructions [here](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/latest/#installation).

Comment: So i have tried the new installation instructions.  I ran into 2 problems.

1. There is no swift folder in the zip archive that you download, only in the git clone.
2. So I tried the git clone and dragged the file `Swift/RLMSupport.swift` into my project and that is where the problem is. On the top of that file it says, `No such module 'Realm'` when trying to import.

So I am still having trouble with Realm for swift.  I seem to be able to compile without the swift file but haven't tried to use it. But I can't get it to compile with.

Comment: I continue to receive the same error. The instructions currently do not work properly in XCode 6/Swift. This is hardly a definitive answer, but I suggest sticking with obj-c for Realm for now. ( I followed the youtube video uploaded today) http://i.imgur.com/M37Q7Th.png

Comment: The instructions will work once Realm 0.86.0 is released, which will happen in the next few hours.

Comment: @jpsim, its still not working via cocopods. i am getting the same error with `0.90.1`

Comment: @RameshVel please file an issue on GitHub where we can help you troubleshoot better if the instructions posted here aren't working for you: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa#installation (click the CocoaPods tab)

Comment: Where is this "Swift/RLMSupport.swift" file? I'm following the CocoaPods instructions and this file doesn't get downloaded (it seems). Any ideas?