# Unable to import Realm framework into swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, realm

I have added Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework files to my project embedded binaries. When I write "import Realm" in my swift file it says "No such module Realm"

I am using Xcode 7 and realm-swift-0.93.2. Could you please help me regarding the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please check that the parent path to `RealmSwift.framework` is listed in the `Framework Search Paths` build settings of your app target. Unlike to Xcode 6, the value is no longer automatically set in Xcode 7 beta1-3 (Maybe it's a bug, fixed in beta4). Normally the value is `$(PROJECT_DIR)`.

[image]

However, `realm-swift-0.93.2` is not compatible with Xcode 7 and Swift 2. Another error will occur even the issue as mentioned above has been resolved. (Maybe `Module file was created by an older version of the compiler`)

To use the RealmSwift with Xcode 7 and Swift 2, you should build the framework from source by yourself, or use a package manager like CocoaPods to build and integrate into your project. I strongly recommend using CocoaPods. The instruction for the installation of the Realm compatible with Swift 2 is here.: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-20

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that not only in your test target (as pointed out by the current docs), but also in the build settings of your app target the parent path to `RealmSwift.framework` is listed in the “Framework Search Paths” build setting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your project but you can try with [Realm Objective-C](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation).

1. Follow the latest instructions.
2. Create a bridging header.
3. Add this in the bridging header:

   `#import "Realm/Realm.h"`
4. Remove any `import Realm` statements from your code, including from `RLMSupport.swift`
5. Now it should work. For example, I test with putting this in my `ViewController.swift`

   ```
   import UIKit

   class Person: RLMObject {
       dynamic var name = ""
       dynamic var birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
   }

   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           let author = Person()
           author.name = "David Foster Wallace"

           // Get the default Realm
           let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

           // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
           realm.beginWriteTransaction()
           realm.addObject(author)
           realm.commitWriteTransaction()

           // Print all Persons
           println(Person.allObjects())
       }
   }
   ```

Which prints:

```
    RLMResults <0x7fa1c3f44760> (
    [0] Person {
        name = David Foster Wallace;
        birthdate = 1970-01-01 00:00:01 +0000;
        }
    )
```

Reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163195/install-realm-in-a-swift-app).

And [HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Relam-Example-with-swift) is working project.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift you need to import RealmSwift instead of Realm.

Answer (score 0):

To include Realm via the Swift Package Manager, the approach would be something like:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SomeExampleApp",
    products: [
        // ...
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //...
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git", 
            from: "3.18.0"
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SomeExampleApp",
            dependencies: ["Realm", "RealmSwift", /*...*/],
            // ...
        )
    ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
)
```

```swift
//
//  SomeExampleAppFile.swift
//
import Foundation
import Realm
import RealmSwift

// code, code, code ...
```